# I'm having problems using factory to test in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

i am using DatabaseTransactions in test class

```
class CorreioApiTest extends TestCase
{

    use DatabaseTransactions;
```

this is my test code,

```
  $user = User::where('email', env('SETUP_USER_EMAIL'))->first();
  $correio = factory(Correio::class)->create();
  $this->response = $this->actingAs($user, 'api')->json(
            'GET',
            '/app/correios/' . $correio->id
        );
  $this->response->assertOk();
```

when i run this test i get

```
  "message": "No query results for model [App\Models\Correio] 27"
  "exception": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException"
  "file": "/var/www/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php"
  "line": 224
```

I think there is a problem with the factory because the $coreio object exists in the test class but cannot be retrieved when I test the request in the get route

UPDATE

I verified that removing the

```
use DatabaseTransactions;
```

the test works correctly but I want to continue using a solution from database transaction in the tests

Comment: Do you have a factory class for the Correio model?

Comment: yes and I verified that the factory is creating the $correio object correctly

Comment: Can you switch from `DatabaseTransactions` to `RefreshDatabase`?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem using a sqlite database for my tests, using this configs in a phpunit.xml

```
 <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
 <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

after this i create a database.sqlite file in database folder of my project and add this config in the config/database.php

```
  'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' =>database_path('database.sqlite'),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

after configuring this run the project's migrations and seeds with the command,

```
php artisan migrate --database=sqlite --seed
```